# Plugin page and capabilities

Tags: capabilities, add-menu-page

i´am developing my own WP plugin with custom functions and i would like to show the new submenu in the standard admin panel for **everyone**, who logs in. My code:

```
$capa = 'administrator' or 'author' or 'visitor';
$this->pagehook = $page =  add_menu_page(__('Myplugin','my_plugin'), __('Myplugin','my_plugin'),$capa, $this->page_id, array($this,'render') )
```

As you can see, i defined 1 variable `$capa`, what can be one of the three strings. My problem is that the plugin is visible only when i´m logged in as **admin**. When I log in as visitor or author, the plugin is not visible.

Can u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$capa` is a PHP expression and will always evaluate to `administrator`. Use the capability `read` instead - every role (by default) has this.

Comment: I would add that only capabilities, and not user roles, should be passed to `add_menu_page`.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I changed my $capa to read, but there is no change in settings panel. Only admin can see the plugin...

Comment: Are you defining custom roles/capabilities?

Comment: Sorry guys, i forgot to comment one condition before my code. Everything is working now. Thanks again.